# jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am in a loop. My classes are dependent on each other, maybe I should have designed it differently, but it was working until recently, until I added @JsonBackReference and @JsonManagedReference to solve an error I got. But now I am getting this error:

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.3.jar:2.13.3]
```

I have tried the solutions like adding value to @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference. I added to @JsonIgnore to variables but these did not work.

These are my classes :

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Auction {
    


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String explanation;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;
    

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date startDate;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date endDate;
        
    private int sellNowPrice;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int startPrice;

    //------------------------
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "auction",
            cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private FileAttachment fileAttachment;

    
    @OneToOne
    private Category category;
    
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "auction", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JsonManagedReference(value="selling-item")
    private List<Bid> bids;
    
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "creator_id")
    @JsonBackReference(value="sell")
    private User creator;
    

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "buyer_id")
    @JsonBackReference(value="buyer")
    private User buyer;
    
    public Auction(AuctionVM auctionVM) {
        this.explanation=auctionVM.getExplanation();
        this.title=auctionVM.getTitle();
        this.startDate=auctionVM.getStartDate();
        this.endDate=auctionVM.getEndDate();
        this.sellNowPrice=auctionVM.getSellNowPrice();
        this.startPrice=auctionVM.getStartPrice();
    }
    
    public Auction() {}
}
```

.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User  implements UserDetails{
    
    

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2725432351214985546L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private long id;
    
    @NotNull(message="Name can not be null")
    @Size(min = 2, max=50, message = "Name must be more than 2 letters ")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    

    @NotNull(message="Username can not be null")
    @UniqueUsername
    @Size(min=5,max=100  )
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;
    
    @NotNull(message="Email can not be null")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;
    
    
    @NotNull(message="Password can not be null")
    @Size(min = 4, max=16 , message = "Password must be a minimum of 4 characters and a maximum of 16 characters. ")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;

    
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "buyer")
    @JsonManagedReference(value="bidder")
    private List<Bid> bids;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "creator")
    @JsonManagedReference(value="sell")
    private List<Auction> productsOnSale;
    

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "buyer")
    @JsonManagedReference(value="buyer")
    private List<Auction> biddedProducts;
    
    
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", 
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;
    
    private String image;
    
    private boolean isApproved;
    
    
    
    
    
    //------------------------------

    
    public User() {
        
    }
    
    public User(UserWithoutRole user) {
        this.name = user.getName();
        this.email = user.getEmail();
        this.username=user.getUsername();
        this.image=user.getImage();
    }
    

   @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        Collection<Role> roles = getRoles();
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
         
        for (Role role : roles) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }
         
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }


    
}
```

.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Bid {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private int id;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "buyer_id")
    @JsonBackReference(value="bidder")
    private User buyer;
    
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "auction_id")
    @JsonBackReference(value="selling-item")
    private Auction auction;
    
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date bidTime;
    
    
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int price;
    
}
```

Where is my mistake idk. If I have to use @JsonIgnore for getters  should i delete @Data and where should i use @JsonIgnore. I tried like this but didn't work.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "creator_id")
@JsonBackReference(value="sell")
@JsonIgnore
private User creator;
```

Comment: What is the initial error you are trying to fix? I guess, something along the lines of being unable to serialize entity due to circular references?

Comment: @Chaosfire the problem that i am getting this error @GetMapping("/auction/{id}")
 public Auction getAuction (@PathVariable int id) {
  return auctionService.findAuction(id);
  
 }

Comment: But what is the **initial** error and **stacktrace**? And what exactly do you try to achieve? If you don't edit question to add this information, and we try to fix the subsequent error you get, we are risking to get tangled in a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).